# Render CSS with Razor Engine + Enabling One Request for Multiple Files

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is my situation...

```
public partial class CssController : Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult Merge(string[] files)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var pathAllowed = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/css"));
            var normalizeFile = Server.MapPath(Url.Content(Path.Combine("~/Content/css", file)));
            if (normalizeFile.StartsWith(pathAllowed) == false)
            {
                return HttpNotFound("Path not allowed");
            }

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(normalizeFile))
            {
                Response.AddFileDependency(normalizeFile);
                builder.AppendLine(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(normalizeFile));
            }
        }

        Response.Cache.VaryByParams["files"] = true;
        Response.Cache.SetLastModifiedFromFileDependencies();
        Response.Cache.SetETagFromFileDependencies();
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

        var css = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(builder.ToString(), new DotlessConfiguration());

        return Content(css, "text/css");
    }

    public string Index()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        return Razor.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Content/css/Global.css")));
    }
}
```

}

Now the public action method was used to get all css files on one request. Also reutrning that and parsing .less files. Well due to lack of editors that support .less, we moved to Razor to parse our css. The bottom string method displays what we are trying to do there. Well plain and simple, how can I integrate both those methods without getting an error.

In our Layout, we are using this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.ActionLinkWithArray("Merge", "Css", new { files = new[] { "StoreManager.less" } })" />
```

to pull all files on one request. Yet this is using the .less Configuration when I wnat to use the RazorEngine.

I hope this explains what I need to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

My favorite solution is [Cassette](https://github.com/andrewdavey/cassette) by Andrew Davey.

In your `_Layout.cshtml` you:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Assets.Scripts.Render()
</head>
```

And in any view that requires javascript:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
    Assets.Scripts.Reference("scripts/utils/date.js");
    Assets.Scripts.Reference("scripts/widgets/calendar.js");
}
```

This will minify (includes `Less`) and condense all your scripts and css into a single files for each.

*This may or may not help but sure does make it easy. It looks as if you're looking for a solution for your current problem but this is definitely an alternative.*

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. Seems like these kinds of utilities are all newborns. Working with html5, mvc3, and entity framework 4.1, I find myself writing a lot of code to do basic system-level things like this. Cassette is really impressive so far, and very actively updating, too.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at all the Nuget projects a lot lately to see what's out there. I found this there one day.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this more mature project: http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/ I think it was designed for MVC2, but seems to work just fine with Razor, too.